# AWS Oracle with SSL java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset AWS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, connection-reset

I am trying to connect a simple java application to an AWS Oracle DB using the SSL connection with protocle=tcps
I have verified below
I have imported the rds-ca-2019.pem and rds-ca-2015.pem file to my trust store and the ssl handshake seems to be fine. I have used the below as outlined in AWS Doc

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class OracleSslConnectionTest {
    private static final String DB_SERVER_NAME = "<dns-name-provided-by-amazon-rds>";
    private static final Integer SSL_PORT = "<ssl-option-port-configured-in-option-group>";
    private static final String DB_SID = "<oracle-sid>";
    private static final String DB_USER = "<user name>";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "<password>";
    // This key store has only the prod root ca.
    private static final String KEY_STORE_FILE_PATH = "<file-path-to-keystore>";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_PASS = "<keystore-password>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        final String connectionString = String.format(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=%s)(PORT=%d))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=%s)))",
                DB_SERVER_NAME, SSL_PORT, DB_SID);
        properties.put("user", DB_USER);
        properties.put("password", DB_PASSWORD);
        properties.put("oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant", "true");
        properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", KEY_STORE_FILE_PATH);
        properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
        properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEY_STORE_PASS);
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, properties);
        // If no exception, that means handshake has passed, and an SSL connection can be opened
    }
}
```

Confirming that I have opened an inbound rule to the instance from teh security group of the Oracle RDS 
I have used many ojdbc drivers 
 ojdbc14.jar
 ojdbc6.jar
ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar

Confirming that I can access the DB without ssl , which mean protocol=tcp and with the designated port for non -ssl

It is when I used the below I get the error 
With protocol=tcps
port=ssl port 
Confirming the trust store path and the password are okay 
Need help in the below error

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:682)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at OracleCon.main(OracleCon.java:33)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.send(Packet.java:419)
    at oracle.net.ns.ConnectPacket.send(ConnectPacket.java:241)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:151)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: I used the below ciphers (SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA)
 (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
  (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
Getting the below error. 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA